# Using a record value in an expression for data source

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

At the moment I have an unbound textbox with this as the data source:

```
=Count("select count(*) from merchandise_groups_merchandise as mgm where mgm.is_enabled = true and mgm.merchandise_group_id = [id]")
```

This just outputs "#Error" in the textbox. There's a field with the name `id` in the form datasource, and if I hardcode an id value, the expression returns the correct count value.

Is this not how to reference a record value in an expression? (Yes, I've also tried `Forms!form_name!id`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DCount`:

```
=DCount("*","merchandise_groups_merchandise","is_enabled = true and merchandise_group_id = " & [id] & "")
```